# How do I make the table row border-bottom not span the full width of the table?

Tags: html, css

So I have a design that I want to make work.  It relies upon a table whose row width occupies the full width of the table.

I have a border bottom whose border stretches the full width of the table.

How do I properly modify the width (horizontal span) of the border so that it covers only a percentage of the full width of the table width?

I have this now (table row)

```
+---------------+
|   table row   |
+===============+
```

I want to change the equals character (border bottom width to be less than the full width of table)

```
+---------------+
|   table row   |
+  ===========  +
```

Note that = is the border bottom.

Is there any to control the row bottom width or do I need to use a padding/margin inside the tbody?

Answer (score 3):

I would use this

```
 <div class="inner">&nbsp;</div>
```

with the style

```
.inner {
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #969696;
}
```

you put this div inside the content of the `td`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This method produces borders under each td whereas what I need is under the tr.

Comment: @Vahe did you tried to add this after last td ? I mean before the </tr>

Comment: @O.Rares you can't have a `div` as a child of a `tr` - the only permitted content of a `tr` per the spec is `td` and `th`.

Comment: @O.Rares, per the sugestion, I get various lines 80% width, outside the table (incorrect placement)

Comment: @Vahe What if instead of the div you put an empty tr an change it's size?You can use the code above and change only height or use a tr with 3 td one is with no style ,one with the border (or background color) and the last one with no style again

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table markup, I'm assuming you have multiple cells in each row (or it's more of a list than a table). The most straightforward way I can think of is to use the `<td>` cells in the last row of your table to carry the border. The first and last cells would not have a `border-bottom` set, while all the `<td>` elements in between those do.

You might be able to apply this CSS with minimal changes to your existing table:

```
tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:first-of-type,
tbody tr:last-child td:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

However this doesn't give you particularly finite control over the width of the bottom border, as the width is tied to the content of those non-outer cells. If that's important, you could use an `::after` pseudo element to show the border:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}

table::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30% // adjust for desired width
  width: 60%; // adjust for desired width
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this. Try to manipulate the 'hr' as your table border - bottom.
Cheers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  width:500px;
    border-left: 1px red solid;
    border-top: 1px red solid;
    border-right: 1px red solid;
}
.box{
    width:500px;
}
.box hr{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Add a border to a table:</h2>

<div class="box">
 <table >
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
    <hr/>
</box>



</body>
</html>
```